# Empty match on end token due to greedyness

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-greedy

I want to parse the space around items of a comma-separated list (the indices are the interesting part for me). Imagine parsing the arguments of a function call.

I'm using the regex `^\s*|\s*,\s*|\s*,?\s*$` for this, which works as intended for most cases. In particular, the beginning and the end *should match with empty matches* iff there is no whitespace (and/or a comma for the end). E.g. `foo` has 2 matches, one at 0-0 and one at 3-3.

Unfortunately, non-empty matches in the back are also followed by an empty match right at the end. Consider the following example ([at regex](https://regex101.com/r/SvsZ7B/1)):

[image]
[image]

Here, the fifth match (23-23) is unintended. I assume this match is found due to greedy nature of *. However, one cannot use the ? operator on the end token $ to make it non-greedy.

Is there a way to express my intended behavior (without the empty match at the end) using JavaScript regexes?

**Edit:** here are some examples (using _ instead of spaces for clarity)

- `foo` 2 matches 0-0, 3-3
- `foo_,_bar` 3 matches 0-0, 3-6, 9-9
- `___foo,_bar,_no_match,_` 4 matches 0-3, 6-8, 11-13, 21-23
- `foo_,bar_,` 3 matches 0-0, 3-5, 8-10
- `_foo_` 2 matches 0-1, 4-5

Comment: Probably more to do with `\s*,?\s*` allowing completely empty matches, since every single token is optional. Changing it to `,\s*$` seems to behave as you would want it where the last match isn't empty.

Comment: @VLAZ As also stated in the question, the empty match is intended, just not if its subsumed by a bigger match. Taking the example from the question, `foo` should have 2 matches, one at 0-0 and one at 3-3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a negative lookahead to the middle alternative so it doesn't match at the end.

And put a negative lookbehind in the last alternative so you won't get two matches when there's whitespace at the end.

```
^\s*|\s*,\s*(?!\s+$)|(?<![\s,])\s*,?\s*$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/A5WjZ3/5)

Comment: Unfortunately, the example in the question `foo` does then not have 2 matches anymore (intended would be one at 0-0 and one at 3-3).

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally removed a `*` in the last alternative. Now it works for `foo`.

Comment: No problem, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, your current solution has the same problem if you have a space after foo, e.g. ` foo ` should only have 2 matches (0-1, 4-5) and not 5-5.

Comment: I added some more examples for clarification

Comment: The problem isn't that `*` is greedy, the problem is that it also matches 0 occurrences. So the empty string at the end always matches, even if there's also a match for another alternative before it.

Comment: I think I figured out the solution, I updated my demo with all your test cases.

Comment: Almost, `bar,` still has the additional empty match.

Comment: Sorry, I've run out of ideas. Lookbehinds have to be fixed length, so I can't make it check for an optional `,`.

Comment: I think a simple option in the lookbehind does the trick: `^\s*|\s*,\s*(?!\s+$)|(?<![\s,])\s*,?\s*$`

Comment: We can also cut the negative lookahead in the second alternative, resulting in `^\s*|\s*,\s*|(?<![\s,])\s*,?\s*$`.